# Detecting if two game objects are overlapping / intersecting Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have what I think is a straight forward question, but my lack of unity knowledge is hindering me.

I have primitive type game objects (e.g. a cube / capsule / sphere) rotated at various angles in my scene. They are already instantiated.

I then add a new game object primitive type to the scene and I want to know if this new game object overlaps / intersects the current primitive types in the scene.

To do this I have been using the `gameobject1.GetComponent<Collider>.bounds.Intersects(gameobject2.GetComponent<Collider>.bounds)`

However this doesn't work because the bounds is a bounding box so even if a game object isn't directly touching one of the primitive type game objects visually, if it's in it's bounding box, it returns that as true (i.e. they intersect) which is not what I want:

[image]

I'm sure there is another way of doing this in unity but I just don't know what I need to do!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It should be possible to modify the boundingbox size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a MeshCollider instead (as long as your objects are simple) then set the MeshCollider IsTrigger property to true.

Then in code you can do:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
}
```

or

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
}
```

When ever an object enters the collider, the above function will be called and you can do what you need to there.

Edit: Your objects will need a rigidbody added to them for the collision to work

Comment: Also, if you just need to know if two object touch each other, you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: All the objects are primitive types so cubes, spheres and cylinders. I’m assuming they have rigidbody’s already since they are part of The unity engine?

Comment: @Mah yes I just need to know whether they touch, true false

Comment: No you have to add them, Add Component > Rigidbody. If you don't want it affected by physics you should mark it as Kinematic

Answer (score 2):

Use MeshCollider, instead of BoxCollider

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]